# Javascript not loading in Django html

Tags: javascript, django

I'm trying to include JavaScript in my html design in Django. I'm getting 304 response but the javascript is not showing on the page. `GET /static/js/app.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0`

I'm loading it in the head tag in html like this
`<script src="{% static 'js/app.js' %}" type="text/javascript" ></script>`

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you running `collectstatic`?https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic

Comment: Try to print anything to console first - just to be sure your js is executed. Then try to find it's iteraction with html page.